# Show that $\sup_{0<x<\infty} (\mathrm{cos}x+\mathrm{sin}\sqrt{2}x)=2$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, dynamical-systems, supremum-and-infimum

This is a problem in V Arnold's Ordinary Differential Equations.

By plotting the function $f(x)=\mathrm{cos}x+\mathrm{sin}\sqrt{2}x$ (the first graph below), I see that the graph is bounded from -2 to 2. But the boundary points $\{2,-2\}$ are not attained by $f(x)$. Intuitively, it seems true that $f(x)$ approaches 2 when both $\mathrm{cos}x$ and $\mathrm{sin}\sqrt{2}x$ approach 1. From the graph of both $\mathrm{cos}x$ and $\mathrm{sin}\sqrt{2}x$ (the second graph below), one can see that around $x=19$, both $\mathrm{cos}x$ and $\mathrm{sin}\sqrt{2}x$ approach 1.

But this doesn't seem like much of a proof. Is there another approach to show this equality? Also, I fail to find an ODE-related approach to this problem.

[image: graph of $f(x)=\mathrm{cos}x+\mathrm{sin}\sqrt{2}x$]

[image: graph of $f(x)=\mathrm{cos}x$ and $f(x)=\mathrm{sin}\sqrt{2}x$]

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. We note that:

$\cos(x)=1$ when $x=2\pi n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$

and

$\sin(\sqrt{2}x)=1$ when $\sqrt{2}x=2\pi n + \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\implies x=\sqrt{2}\pi n+\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}\left(\pi n+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$.

The values for the cosine term are all rational multiples of $\pi$, and those for the sine term are all irrational ones, proving that both will never be $1$ at the same time.

But, we can get arbitrarily close. Are you familiar with the property from algebra that given two integers $x,y$, any multiple of $\gcd(x,y)$ can be constructed via linear combinations? A similar rule will help you demonstrate that you can get as arbitrarily close to $2$ as you want here. I freely admit I do not have the details worked out, at which point mathematicians usually say "I'll leave that part as an exercise".

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the construction of gcd(x,y) via linear combination. But I couldn't see how it will help me to demonstrate that the sum can get arbitrarily close to 2.

Comment: @Orca_1 I thought about this a bit more today, so you're in luck. I *think* I know how to do it, but before I try to write it all out, what is this for? If it is for an undergraduate or introductory graduate course in analysis, my idea won't be of much help. Secondly, have you had any courses or experience in field theory and specifically with field extensions and rings of the form $R[\sqrt{-w}]$?

Comment: This is a practice problem in V Arnold's Ordinary Differential Equations. I have learned field extensions and rings of the form $R[\sqrt{D}]$ for $D>0$.

Comment: @Orca_1 dezdichao seems to be willing to type the rest of the info, I'll yield since I need to study for my qualifying exams.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove that you can find integers $m$ and $n$ such that $2\pi m$ and $ \sqrt{2}\pi n+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$ are arbitrarily close. But this is a routine application of the [Equidiistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem). 
See if you can figure the rest out on your own.

**Proof**:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. By the equidistribution theorem above, $a_n = \{\frac{4n+1}{4\sqrt{2}}\}$ numbers are equidistributed in the interval $(0,1)$. Hence, we can find $n$ such that $a_n<\frac{\varepsilon}{2\pi}$. Now let $m = \frac{4n+1}{4\sqrt{2}} - a_n = \frac{n}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} - a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$. By our construction, $$|2\pi(m-\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}})| = |2\pi m - \sqrt{2}\pi n-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}| = 2\pi 
a_n<\varepsilon.$$

Note that in the original comment, I wrongly cited Dirichlet's approximation theorem instead of the equidistribution theorem. Also, this theorem proved by using only pigeon-hole principle, so this is basically nothing advanced.

Comment: I have tried the following, please help me see if it's valid.

Comment: I want to find integers $m$ and $n$ such that $|2\pi m- \sqrt{2}\pi(n+\frac{1}{4})|$ is arbitrarily small, i.e. $\sqrt{2}\pi|\sqrt{2}m-\frac{4n+1}{4}|$ is arbitrarily small. By the thrm, for any irrational number $\sqrt{2}m$, there exists rational number $\frac{4n+1}{4}$ such that $|\sqrt{2}m-\frac{4n+1}{4}|<\frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: Not quite. You want to find such $m,n$,  given a small $\varepsilon.$ I will type up a solution later in the day.

Comment: @Orcha_1 you are very close. Thanks dezdichado for stepping up. Much appreciated. Will upvote when the answer is there.